# Why are .scala Files not Showing up From jar Dependancies?

Tags: scala, jar, import, sbt

I'm using some unmanaged dependancies for an sbt project, so I created a jar file and placed it inside the /lib directory.

now when I type:

```
org.foo.bar.qaz.etc
```

the IDE is only aware of the packages but can never import the .scala files inside those packages,
What do I need to fix?

thanks

Comment: The jar file doesn't contain any `.scala` files. They only contain `.class` files.

Comment: So in order to add a scala dependancy to my project I just add it to the /lib directory as is?

Comment: I guess. that should work as long as /lib is in your classpath. Alternatively you can publish your jar to a your local mvn/ivy cache and then add it as a dependency to your build.sbt file.

Comment: But putting the dependancies into a jar wont work because I have .scala files, not .class

Comment: If the jar won't load scala files from my projects lib why would it be able to do so from a mvm/ivy cache